# Java appends random characters and overwrites string

Tags: java, string

I need to read the input from the console byte by byte and then print it out and then check if it equals "exit".

Here's my code:

```
int inChar = 1;
String input = "";
char correctChar;
// code
try {
    while (inChar != '\n') {
        inChar = System.in.read();
        correctChar = (char) inChar;
        if (inChar != '\n') {
            input += correctChar;
        } // end if
    } // end while
} // end try
catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Error reading from user");
} // end catch
System.out.println("Hello " + input + "AQ");
```

For some reason when I run the code and type exit, it prints to the screen:

`AQllo exit`

If I check if `input.equals("exit")` it says no. My guess is somehow the string is not null terminated, because that was the problem when I encountered something like this in assembly, but I cant seem to fix this Java code. Am I even reading the bytes correctly from the screen?

Comment: Have you looked into the [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class? That might allow you to simplify your code quite a bit.

Comment: I did but for some reason I have to read it byte by byte, and doesn't the scanner read the whole input at one time?

Comment: yes, but I got it to work now. I just did if (inChar > 32 && inChar < 126) { and it fixed it. so it has something to with a byte

Comment: I'm not seeing the same output that you are with the overriding bit, but I believe that `input` contains what you want it to contain.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're working on a Windows machine, right?

The problem is, if you enter something to the console, you will enter: `exit\r\n`, since `\r\n` is the line delimiter for Windows.

Now, you're "ignoring" `\n` due to your checks `while (inChar != '\n')` and `if (inChar != '\n')`, but you append `\r` to your `input` String. `\r` is [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) which moves the cursor to the start of the line.

Now let's check your output:

```
System.out.println("Hello " + input + "AQ");
```

You're printing this:

> Hello exit\rAQ

Some consoles (not the one in some IDEs like Eclipse or IDEA) interpret the `\r` and will move the cursor. That means, you're moving the cursor to the start of the line and then print *"AQ"*, which overwrites the first two letters *"He"*, hence the output:

> AQllo exit

To fix that, just add an additional check for `\r`:

```
int inChar = 1;
String input = "";
char correctChar;
// code
try {
    while (inChar != '\n' && inChar != '\r') {
        inChar = System.in.read();
        correctChar = (char) inChar;
        if (inChar != '\n' && inChar != '\r') {
            input += correctChar;
        } // end if
    } // end while
} // end try
catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Error reading from user");
} // end catch
System.out.println("Hello " + input + "AQ");
```

Answer (score -2):

I would try this:

```
int inChar = 1;
   String input = "Hello ";
   char correctChar; 


// code        
   try {
     while (inChar != '\n') {
       inChar = System.in.read();
       correctChar = (char)inChar;     
       if (inChar != '\n') {
         input += correctChar;
       } // end if
     } // end while
input+="AQ";
   } // end try
   catch (IOException e){
     System.out.println("Error reading from user");
   } // end catch
System.out.println(input);
```

Comment: *Why* would you try this?

Comment: @Makoto Isn't the problem the System.out.println?

Comment: Not necessarily.  Besides, I'm not even seeing the same thing that the OP is, so I can't tell you if the println is the error at all.

Comment: @Makoto It is and I guess you're not seeing it, because you either don't use Windows, or you run your code in an IDE. I hope my answer explains the problem well.

Comment: @Tom:  Actually, it's both; I run on Linux *and* I use IntelliJ.  So I wouldn't be seeing the same thing, which makes sense.  However, this answer still doesn't explain what's going on or why the output would be what it is.

Comment: @Makoto First of all: I like that you're using these two "things" :D. And yes, this answer needs an explanation.